# Problem with assembly statements in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, assembly

I encountered a piece of assembly code in a C program I was trying to run in FreeBSD 64-bit.

```
void  *curbrk;   
__asm__ __volatile__(
        "movl .curbrk, %%eax;"
        "movl %%eax, %0"
            : "=r" (curbrk)
            :: "%eax"
    );
```

I get an error like "mov missing suffix or operand".(The above code follows AT&T syntax) What determines the syntax i should use for the code - The compiler (gcc follows AT&T syntax) or the processor (I'm working on an Intel Processor). Is the problem due to the fact that the code is in AT&T syntax or is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a 64-bit GCC, the above code will not complete unless you use the -m32 switch to output 32-bit object code, because the 64-bit pointer value will not fit into the 32-bit EAX register.  Either use -m32 to generate 32-bit output, or use rax inplace of eax and change the movl's to mov (without 'l')

Comment: Do you know the rationale for picking `mov` instead of `movq` in GCC's inline assembly syntax for amd64 instructions?

Comment: @Pascal: You can use both `mov` and `movq`: `mov` instructs the assembler to "guess" the target data size, whereas `movq` states that we are talking about 64-bit values. For instance, `mov 0, foo` will not compile, because the assembler does not know the size of the variable `foo`, whereas `mov 0, %%rax` will be implicitly understood as a `movq` because `%rax` is a 64-bit register. Note that GCC does not understand any of the above: with inline assembly, GCC just dumps the string into the generated assembly (after replacing the `%`-things): the _assembler_ deals with it.